# Community driven-image contests

Tags: component, extensions, extension-request

I want to build a site where:

1. An user creates a contest, for example, entitled "Landscapes"
2. Every user can submit images to that contest
3. Every user can vote within those images
4. Eventually the contest ends, and there's a winner
5. In the future it will be more complex, so it should be open to modifications

Can someone help me figure out the best way to do this?

- I guess that first, I need a community / social extension. For that, I'm taking a look at Jomsocial, Easy Social, and community builder. Any ideas wich one would be better for something like this?
- For the contest / poll with images, I found an extension that might be modified to do this, but their site is currently down. Its name is [simgallery](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/photos-a-images/galleries/simgallery). It mentions a ranking mode that might be useful.

Any other ideas? Maybe there is another extension that would fit better? The key features are that any user can create this contests (not only the admin), that each user's submission to the contest should be an image (so it must be viewed as a gallery), and that each submission can be voted.

Any ideas? Maybe I'm heading in the wrong direction and I could do it in another way? I know I will have to program quite a lot. I'm trying also to keep it as inexpensive as possible (those extensions can be expensive).

Comment: It's about development in joomla, using extensions that already exists, adapting them or re-coding. This might be used for other cases too.

Comment: Hi! I'm the creator of the SIMGallery you mentioned, and I just want you to know that I have created a contest extension that is **exactly** what you're looking for: SIMContests https://www.simbunch.com/products/simcontests. The demo can be found https://www.simbunch.com/demos/simcontests

Answer (score 1):

Core Design Photo Contest http://extensions.joomla.org/profile/extension/photos-a-images/galleries/core-design-photo-contest might fit the bill.

Comment: The problem with this extension is that contests are not created by users themselves. Contest are created by admins.